# Calling text from a different php file

Tags: php

I'm looking to find a way to make a `config.php` file to setup the website easier. See below;

**config.php** -

```
#Community Name
$commname = "Community A",

#Community Phone Number
$commphone = "0123456789",
```

**index.php** -

```
<h1>Community Name: <?php echo($commname) ?></h1>
<h2>Phone Number: <?php echo($commphone) ?></h2>
```

**contact.php** (same setup, just a different page) -

```
<h1>Community Name: <?php echo($commname) ?></h1>
<h2>Phone Number: <?php echo($commphone) ?></h2>
```

I'm fairly new to PHP so I'm not sure if `echo` is the best way to do it or not.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't like to use echo you can display a var with `<?=`, Example: `<h1>Community Name: <?= ($commname) ?></h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ye so just create a config.php

```
<?php

$serverName = "Server Name";

?>
```

Then inside your other php files include the config file by doing

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . "/config.php");

?>
```

Then where you want to use the variable do

`<title> <?php echo $serverName; ?> </title>`

Answer (score 1):

It's not hte best way but if it's working - why not?

For example you can use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and use [Dotenv package](https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv) to create `.env` file in your root folder and add some variables like:

```
COMMUNITY_NAME=APP //APP_NAME
COMMUNITY_PHONE=88816259
```

and then you can add to your root page(router or something else) and all variables will be stored after loading page with this code:

```php
$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
$dotenv->load();
```

All variables will be able in global varable **$_ENV**

```php
echo $_ENV['COMMUNITY_NAME']; //APP_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

**config.php**

```
<?php
$comm = [
'name' => 'Community A',
'address' => 'Baker Street',
'phone' => '0123456789'
];
```

**other PHP files**

```
<?php
include 'config.php'; // Assuming that config.php is inside the same folder of the others
?>

<h1>Communities</h1>
<p>Name: <?=$comm['name']?></p>
<p>Address: <?=$comm['address']?></p>
<p>Phone: <?=$comm['phone']?></p>
```

I prefer to use an associative array (here `$comm`), instead of single variables, because it makes the code more clear and neat (it's just my opinion).